# can you leave slow cooker on for 10 and a half hour i food takes 8hrs to cook

Tags: meat

If you leave a slow cooker cooking for 10 and a half hours on slow, and the food takes 8 hours, will it damage anything?

Comment: its lamb shank potatoes and veg

Answer (score 0):

As long as there's enough liquid in the pot to stop it burning, it should be fine. If you have meat in there it may get a little dry, if the cut is lean.

Comment: its lamb shank potatoes and frozen veg ive got gravy in there just covering the contents.

Comment: Shank is quite fatty, should be fine. It will certainly be tender.